# Algebra in non-type variable subscript space

Tags: python, math, sympy

[github issue post](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/22759)

Summarize the problem
trying to solve: this math problem using Python Sympy in Jupyter Notebook IDE: [picture of math problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCEg7.png)

Describe what you’ve tried:
[picture of my jupyter notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2JT8.png)

Here I have imported sympy, created a non-type variable `a_n`, then tried to rewrite the expression in my notebook. The problem I came across was trying to do algebra in the subscript space.

```
from sympy import *
a_n = symbols('a_n')
Eq(a_n,3*a_n-2)
```

---

Update after 6 hours

with help from the comment by user dancxviii I have changed the code to be

```
from sympy import *
from sympy import sequence
from sympy.abc import n
a_n = symbols("a_n")
a_n1 = symbols("a_{n-1}")
a_n2 = symbols("a_{n-2}")
a_n3 = symbols("a_{n-3}")
e1 = Eq(a_n,3*a_n2+(28*a_n2*a_n3)/a_n1)
e1
```

displayed in LateX on notebook it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UoKh.png)
Hoping to be able to do .subs() on a_n and replace the actual value of n if that's possible

Comment: `a_n-2` means the nth element, minus 2.  It does not mean the (n-2)th element.  Are you supposed to use `sympy` for this task?   https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/series/sequences.html

Comment: a_n-2 should read as "a with the subscript value of (n-2)" and this task isn't restricted to sympy

Comment: I know that's how you WANT it to read, but that's not what Python is going to see.  That was my point.

Comment: The code you have in the update doesn't expose any relationship between `a_n` and `a_n1` and `a_n2`.  `sympy` has options for dealing with sequences.  That's where you need to explore.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
from sympy import *
a_n = symbols('a_n')
a_n_minus_2 = symbols('a_{n-2}')
Eq(a_n,3*a_n_minus_2)
```

In case you are having trouble with the problem given (I can't tell from your question), the best way to solve it is:

Let r_n = a_(n + 2) / a_(n).
After dividing the recurrence relation on both sides by a_(n - 2):

r_(n - 2) = 3 + 28 / (r_(n - 3))     =>       r_n = 3 + 28 / r_(n - 1)

The fixed points for this recurrence relation are at -4 and 7. Therefore the closed form will have the form:

r_n = (w * 7^n + x * (-4)^n) / (y * 7^n + z * (-4)^n)

This is a 4 variable system where 1 of the variables is redundant, so you can set w to 1.

If you plug this form into the initial recurrence relation with the initial value of r_0 = 17 / 6, the resulting series of linear equations (done on paper) gives:

```
w = 1
x = -100 / 287
y = 1 / 7
z = 25 / 287
```

Comment: The LateX in my notebook doesn't display this very well.  https://i.imgur.com/TzdmBfy.png https://i.imgur.com/5qsdAk1.png  I was hoping I could do a .subs() method on the n value for a_(n-4) and maybe loop things

Comment: Oh my bad, edited the answer to get rid of the error. Are you actually supposed to solve it using sympy, or just write out the latex?

Comment: If you have the option not to use sympy for solving something, Id take it since in my experience sympy is extremely reliable for actual mathematical functions.